# How do I concatenate non-empty, disconnected nodes?

Tags: jquery

When I try to build up a sequence of disconnected DOM nodes using `.after`, it works fine if they are empty:

```
[14:56:45.186] $('<span></span>').after('<p></p>');
[14:56:45.193] ({0:({}), length:2, prevObject:{0:({}), length:1}, context:(void 0), selector:".after([object Arguments])", 1:({})})
```

But if I try to add any text in the first node, it fails:

```
[14:56:41.521] $('<span>test</span>').after('<p></p>');
[14:56:41.525] ({0:({}), length:1})
```

If I assign that result to a variable and try to inspect it, it appears as if `after` had never been called at all.

What's going on here, and how do I work around it?

---

Edit: For those interested, I ended up writing the following wrappers which seem to be making life much easier for me:

```
function tag(name) {
    return function(contents, options) {
        var o = options || {};
        var is_array = $.type(contents) === "array";
        if (!is_array) {
            o.text = contents;
        }
        result = $('<' + name + ' />', o);
        if (is_array) {
            $.each(contents, function(i, child) { result.append(child); });
        }
        return result;
    }
}
var span = tag('span');
var div = tag('div');
```

Comment: Interesting... this works as expected in jQuery 1.8.3, but not in jQuery 1.9 (released this morning). http://jsfiddle.net/RqKCL/1/

Comment: The code paths are different (`<span></span>` uses `createElement()`, `<span>test</span>` uses `createDocumentFragment()`). Very possibly a bug.

Comment: Usually, you shouldn't be setting any attributes before the element has been made. $('<span />').text('test').

Comment: @KevinB I appear to be using a quite old version of jQuery actually (1.6.1), because it comes with jsTree, and I can't get jsTree to use a version of jQuery from a CDN, but only the one in its own `_lib` folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clarify your bug -- when I run your code in my JavaScript console, I get the following:

```
> $('<span></span>').after('<p></p>');
[<span>​</span>​,<p>​</p>]
> $('<span>test</span>').after('<p></p>');
[<span>​test​</span>​]
```

According to [the jQuery 1.9 upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#after-before-and-replacewith-with-disconnected-nodes):

> Prior to 1.9, .after(), .before(), and .replaceWith() would attempt to
>   add or change nodes in the current jQuery set if the first node in the
>   set was not connected to a document, and in those cases return a new
>   jQuery set rather than the original set. ***This created several
>   inconsistencies and outright bugs--the method might or might not
>   return a new result depending on its arguments!*** As of 1.9, these
>   methods always return the original unmodified set and attempting to
>   use .after(), .before(), or .replaceWith() on a node without a parent
>   has no effect--that is, neither the set or the nodes it contains are
>   changed.

So: The behavior you've observed is a bug which results from using `.after()` on a node without a parent. As of 1.9, the jQuery dev team has solved this inconsistency by removing it entirely -- using `.after()` this way should always return the initial node without the `<p>` after it ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/vg4xh/)).

**Workaround:**

Push your DOM nodes onto a simple array. Or append them to a parent node, then get all the children: ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/2Xa6r/))

```
$chain = $('<div>').append('<span></span>').append('<p>qwer</p>').children();
```

Comment: What console is that? That looks a lot nicer for debugging jQuery stuff than the one built in to Firefox. Anyway, I decided that the nodes in question really ought to be in a container div anyway (to facilitate CSS stuff later), and ended up solving the problem by making some wrappers for creating nested div and span elements (with children in an array or a simple text child, and additional arguments passed to jQuery). Thanks for the investigation, though! Definitely answers the question and gets the checkmark.

Comment: Chrome console, nothing fancy. Props to @KevinB for pointing out the 1.9 update to me.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new nodes is usually done like this:

```
$('<span />', {text: 'test'}).after($('<p />'));
```

Comment: This appears to work, but why doesn't it work the other way? The `span` node thus created *seems* to be identical, except that it reacts differently to `.after`.